# Caulking in a glass pane on a skylight

Tags: caulking, glass, caulk, weatherstripping, skylight

A branch fell and broke my skylight glass. I ordered replacement glass, and now I'm wondering the proper way to caulk it in. First, do I need to caulk it in? I don't see any caulk residue from the previous glass. Second, if I do, do I use silicone? And what's the proper way? Put a bead on the edge underneath and just set the pane down on it?

[image]

Comment: You need some type of seal there.  Either a rubber gasket or caulking to keep water/air out.  For a roof I would place a bead of caulking to set the glass in and a bead along the edges on the top side.

Comment: Silicone in each case?